# WIN 10 PostgreSQL DB symbols are unreadable

Tags: windows, postgresql, cmd

I'm having a problem with saved data in my PostgreSQL DB. The symbols for the VARCHAR columns are unreadable. I've researched it a lot and can't seem to find a solution to my problem.

Here's what I see:

1. [cmd DB table view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghFp2.png)

2. DB creation query:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE test
    WITH 
    OWNER = random
    ENCODING = 'UTF8'
    LC_COLLATE = 'English_United Kingdom.1252'
    LC_CTYPE = 'English_United Kingdom.1252'
    TABLESPACE = pg_default
    CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

3. Win 10 version - Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.685]

4. PostgreSQL 12.4

I don't think it's the cmd or PowerShell, because the characters are all scrambled in the pgAdmin4 as well, when I run a query to see records from the table. Ex. [pgAdmin4 view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AFl9.png)

I tried `chcp 65001`. I tried `SET PGCLIENTENCODING = 'UTF8'` as well.

If you need more info, please let me know. Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
To generate the data for the 3 columns, I use org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.random(6). I've tried it now with org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(6) and it seems to work fine.

[image: PowerShell screenshot of DB table result]

Comment: Try to use a different font for `cmd.exe`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nope. It sadly didn't work.

Comment: How many fonts did you try? You might need to experiment a bit before you find the one that is capable of displaying those characters. You could check which font your browser uses for Unicode characters

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include an example of a name, and the characters stored for that name in the database?  As text, not as an image.

Comment: Thank you, @a_horse_with_no_name. I tried all of them and was not sure if I'm doing it correctly, because when I clicked OK, the font wouldn't change for the CMD. It did save the new settigs though. Even so, there's no difference. I'll keep at it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb That's a good point. However I'm using org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.random(6) for the 3 columns and didn't really know the values. I'm noticing something interesting though. When I use RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic(), it does the trick and I can see the symbols fine.